# How to stream a video formatted in hls, m3u8 in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

In database, videos are saved in m3u8 format as shown below. I want to open video when I click on button or download it. I read [this](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg). But still not clear for me? Thanks in advance.

`dfa7088-9d3c-4b23-0010a-59fc63f4441d/hls/qe8b807916f8816a.m3u8`

```
@if( $item->media_type=='v')
                                        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
                                        <video id="video" src=" https://cdn.kenan.net/{{ $item->media_path}}" controls width="200px" height="200px"></video>
                                        <script>
                                            if(Hls.isSupported())
                                            {
                                                var video = document.getElementById('video');
                                                var hls = new Hls();
                                                hls.loadSource('playlist.m3u8');
                                                hls.attachMedia(video);
                                                hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function()
                                                {
                                                    video.play();
                                                });
                                            }
                                            else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'))
                                            {
                                                video.src = 'playlist.m3u8';
                                                video.addEventListener('canplay',function()
                                                {
                                                    video.play();
                                                });
                                            }
                                        </script>
                                @else@endif
```

Comment: did you change playlist.m3u8 with your url in hls.loadSource('playlist.m3u8');

Comment: yes ı updated it it works thnks